# URL redirect in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, url

If someone click on the product in magento 1.7.0.2 instead of going to the product page it should refer to external affiliate url can anybody help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Most frontend templates should use `$product->getProductUrl()` to print product url

```
/**
 * Retrieve Product URL
 *
 * @param  bool $useSid
 * @return string
 */
public function getProductUrl($useSid = null)
{
    return $this->getUrlModel()->getProductUrl($this, $useSid);
}
```

So you'd rewrite that method of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class to replace default code with your desired functionality

Depending by the url structure you need it could be easier or harder

For instance, if that affiliate urls mean just adding a parameter in the url you could append that to product url. If that affiliate urls mean a totally different url, involving other domains, etc... then you'd directly write your own `getProductUrl()` function

If you want to register that urls with solutions like Magmi (I personally wouldn't recommend that tool, unless you are working with a very simple catalog) then I think your best approach should be to create a new attribute, register the full url there, and then return it in `getProductUrl()` function

Comment: can you please elaborate and also tell me that how can i upload respective affiliate product URL through MAGMI

Comment: Done, I have updated the answer